# Is there a way to redirect from the feature bdd step to the step definition function in VS code please for pytest Bdd framework

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest-bdd

Is there any pytest bdd plugin which could solve this problem, please.

I am using Pytest BDD extension in VS code, I am not able to navigate to step definition from feature file, if the step has a parameters in it.

Plugin I tried: [plugin link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vtenentes.bdd&ssr=false#overview)

For example in the below example **user A** is a parameter

**Feature file.**

```
Given the user logs in as user A
```

**step definition:**

```
@given(parsers.parse("the user logs in as {user_name}"))
def login(user_name):
```

Comment: you can try [BDD Goto Step](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-bdd-gotostep)

Comment: Thanks rivoV8, BDD goto step works only for behave or cucumber, mine is pytest-bdd.

Comment: have you tried it, it should support Python, if not show me a section of the feature file and the step file.py file, and I will update the extension

Comment: I will add the support for `parser.xxxx()` and custom fields like `blabla %start% blabla`

Comment: `BDD Goto Step` v0.3.0 should handle steps with `parser.XXXX()`

Comment: Hi rioV8, Have you tried with Pytest-BDD, it is not working for that.

Comment: My folder structure is as features -> module_name -> name.feature and the step definition is step_defs->module_name->name.py

Comment: I have also changed the include and exclude path.

Comment: show a diagram of the workspace folders, which folder is a sub folder of ...., like the `tree` command in Unix

Comment: what are the values of **include and exclude path** you use, try include = `step_defs/**/*.*`